# Magento cart information for external website

Tags: magento, cart

Environment: Magento Enterprise 1.12, Redhat Linux

I'm trying to develop a stand-alone php page in Magento (Enterprise 1.12) with the minimal code to display shopping cart information. This would be used by an external website that displays basic cart information from the Magento store. I'm trying to avoid a full-blown custom MVC model if possible since I'm just trying to get minimal read-only information.

I want to display:

- the number of items in the shopping cart (whether or not they have
  logged in)
- the product names in the cart if it's not empty
- whether or not the user is logged in
- customer name if they have logged in

I've seen many posts about this on the net and have tried all the examples without success.

Here's what I am trying:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// The following three variables are successfully set
// but they don't help with what I'm trying to do

$session = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('frontend');
$cartid = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('CART');
$sid = Mage::getModel("core/session")->getEncryptedSessionId();
echo "session=$session <br />\n";
echo "cartid=$cartid <br />\n";
echo "sid=$sid  <br />\n"; 

// None of the following seem to work, whether or not I''m logged in
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
echo "cart items count: $cart <br />\n";
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
echo "cart items count: $cart <br />\n";
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
echo "cart items count: $cart <br />\n";
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
echo "cart items count: $cart <br />\n";
$count = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
echo "cart items count: $cart <br />\n";

// None of the following seem to work. I'm logged in, but the following code says I'm not.
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
if($session->isLoggedIn()) { echo "logged in <br />\n"; } else { echo "not logged in <br />\n"; }
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
if($session->isLoggedIn()) { echo "logged in <br />\n"; } else { echo "not logged in <br />\n"; }
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

I set-up the cookie path via the admin section under System-> Configuration->Web->Session Cookie Management.

I then created a test.php and copied your code into the file with the addition of the line just after the Mage::app():

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, but it returns a null value, with or without anything in the cart. Same result whether or not I'm logged in.

Comment: Try setting your cookie path to / in the system admin under System-> Configuration->Web->Session Cookie Management.

Comment: Or try the line Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend')); after the Mage::app() call.

Comment: Thanks, I also just tried Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend')); as you describe but there's no change in behavior. As before, cart quantity is not showing up and it's not detecting if the user is logged in. I am logged in and have 2 items in the cart, but none of the attempts are showing the number of items in the cart or detecting that I'm logged in.

Comment: I should mention that all the cookies are being correctly detected. See the first few lines after Mage::app();. But I have *not* started the checkout process, so I am wondering if the 'checkout/cart' model perhaps is not what I want to for the cart contents?

Comment: For me after making the cookie path change and creating a test.php file with your code I can add an item to the cart and then it will appear on my test.php. All I can say more is that without the line Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend')); it does not work for me. In both cases the cookies are coming through fine for me also but the cart information will only display after the call to core/session.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback very much but I have rechecked everything and I am not seeing the solution you describe. I have confirmed a) The cookie path os set to / in System-> Configuration->Web->Session Cookie Management; b) I have placed the line of code you describe just after Mage::app(); c) I flushed the cache; d) I retried adding an item to the cart on 2 browsers. Could you please post the complete code of the script that is working for you. It should be 5 lines of code. Also could you please confirm that you are using EE 1.12.